# Problemas com o texto listview por cima dos ícones

Tags: android, ios, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

Isto acontece no Android e IOS.

Quando o nome da loja ou o do lojista é muito grande o texto fica sobre a imagem. E o cliente quer a imagem do lado direito, e do lado esquerdo não tenho este problemas com as imagens.

O texto está alinhado por `Leading` e o `Trimming = Character`.

[image: SS]

Comment: Penso que este problema precisa de soluções distintas para as diferentes plataformas(iOS e Android).. os problemas não podem ser as mesmas uma vez que os erros devem ser diferentes. devias remover a tag de iOS a esta questao

Comment: @DaSilva este problema estava acontecendo em iOS e Android, porque estou usando uma IDE(Delphi Xe6) para as duas plataformas, por isso coloquei a Tag. São problemas distintos de layouts para as duas plataformas que foram resolvidos, mas vlw pela dica !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Problema Resolvido !!!**

Como neste `listview` eu não estava usando a propriedade `Acessory`,  somente os ícones e o texto, resolvi  colocar a propriedade como `Visible = true`, e tirei a opacidade `Opacity = 0`, com isso o texto se encolheu e está respeitando o limite dos ícones.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]